# Could not find sprockets-2.0.0.beta.9 in any of the sources

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I'm getting this error on bundle install

```
$ bundle install
NOTE: Gem.source_index is deprecated, use Specification. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem.source_index called from /Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:3.
NOTE: Gem.source_index is deprecated, use Specification. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem.source_index called from /Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/source.rb:162.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#each is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#each called from /Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/source.rb:162.
NOTE: Gem.source_index is deprecated, use Specification. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem.source_index called from /Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/source.rb:162.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#each is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#each called from /Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/source.rb:162.
Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/
Could not find sprockets-2.0.0.beta.9 in any of the sources
```

This is a new codebase I got from a friend and I'm having problems running it on my computer. I have created the same rvm gemset. The Gemfile is as follows:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'
gem 'rack', :git => 'git://github.com/rack/rack.git'
gem 'rdiscount', :git => 'https://github.com/rtomayko/rdiscount.git'
gem 'stringex'

gem 'mysql'
gem 'mysql2'
gem 'oauth'
gem 'twitter'
gem 'gmail'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec', :git => 'https://github.com/rspec/rspec.git'
  gem 'rspec-rails', :git => 'https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails.git'
  gem 'rspec-mocks', :git => 'https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks.git'
  gem 'rspec-core', :git => 'https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core.git'
  gem 'rspec-expectations', :git => 'https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations.git'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'steak', :git => 'https://github.com/cavalle/steak.git'
  gem 'factory_girl', :git => 'https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl.git'
  gem 'unicorn'
  gem 'capistrano'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
end
```

I'm assuming this is downloading the latest Rails version? I believe that may be the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a good idea to point to the master branch of a git repository, especially if you don't commit your `Gemfile.lock` in the SCM.

I encourage you to replace the `:git` references to use the gem version.

You can also remove duplicate dependencies. Example, if you include `rspec-rails` you don't need to list `rspec-core` and all `rspec-` libraries. They are already listed in the `rspec-rails` depedency list. Listing all dependencies and pointing them to the master branch is for sure the cause of several headaches.

Also, why are you using the mysql gem twice?

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.1.0'
gem 'rdiscount'
gem 'stringex'

gem 'mysql'
gem 'mysql2'
gem 'oauth'
gem 'twitter'
gem 'gmail'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.6.0'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'steak'
  gem 'factory_girl'
  gem 'unicorn'
  gem 'capistrano'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
end
```

Comment: when you say point to the master branch, do you mean I should make a Fork of the code instead of cloning it?

Comment: No, I mean you should use a stable gem release, not the git master repository, unless really required. See my example.